# Java: Authentication and Authorization with iOS/Android/Angular as client

Tags: java, spring, firebase, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I am looking for building an iOS/Android and Angular app with Java at the backend(REST API). Java will use spring framework. I am looking for the options for User authentication. iOS/Android App will be used by the client and Angular web app will be used my management. Angular web users will have different roles so requirement requires authentication(email and password) as well as authorization. Considering this I was thinking of using Spring Security with a custom UserDetailService. However I guess that will have issues with cookies. I looked into AWS Cognito Identity and Firebase and got more confused. It will be a great help if someone can share there experience with such requirement.

Answer (score 3):

i had created basic login application in angular application by referring the links:

1. http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/angularjs-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

and i have used cakePHP3 for rest API generation and Token is generated on the the basis of JWT, JSON Web Token (JWT) is a JSON-based open standard used for passing claims between two parties in the context of web application environment. These token are specially designed to be very compact and URL safe. Their usability in the context of web browser single sign-on is also remarkable. JWT claims are useful for passing identities’ verification between service providers and identity providers. you'll find the reference links on internet.

for android and IOS you need to learn JSON parsing first. In android, JSON parsing can be done using OKHttpclient/Volley "android hive" is best site to learn jsonParsing and in IOS jsonParsing can be done using AFNetworking.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The Ideal Project for you is [Spring Security OAuth2](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html). With this you can make your REST API Stateless and no need to worry about Cookies and Sessions.